# How to name a file via Dropdown menu before uploading it in PHP?

Tags: php, html, web, upload, server

The aim is to let people upload language examples as audio. The files shall get the name of the language chosen by the user. A language list shall be provided as a dropdown menu.

The actions in a row: 
 1. User selects language name from dropdown. 
 2. User selects local audiofile. 
 3. User presses upload button.
 4. Script renames the file provided by the user with the language chosen from the dropdown. 
 5. Ideally, it si able to recognize if there are already files with this name available. If yes, it shall give the following files numbers like "maltese01.wav, maltese02.wav" and so on.

Since php is new for me, that´s where i´m stuck. Any help is appreciated. This is what I got working so far. The script is adopted from a tutorial.

```
<?php

    if(isset($_FILES['sound'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['sound']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['sound']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['sound']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['sound']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['sound']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("wav","aiff","mp3","m4a","mp4","ogg");       
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a WAV, MP3, MP4, M4A or OGG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 8388608){
    $errors[]='Sorry. Your file ist quite large. Maximum file size is 8 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"sounds/".$file_name);
        echo "Thank you!";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="sound" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: bring in the language the user has selected as a $_POST var

Answer (score 1):

This adds a random number to the file name, You shouldn't use the filename direct as it's a security risk, I've left it in at the top but if I was you I'd take it out of there altogether and just make your own straight away. This searches the dir to see if filename exists already and adds a 1 if it does. should work, let me know.

```html
<?php
$language=htmlentities($_POST['language']);
    if(isset($_FILES['sound'])){
        $errors= array();
        $file_name = $_FILES['sound']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['sound']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['sound']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['sound']['type'];   
    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['sound']['name'])));

    $expensions= array("wav","aiff","mp3","m4a","mp4","ogg");       
    if(in_array($file_ext,$expensions)=== false){
        $errors[]="extension not allowed, please choose a WAV, MP3, MP4, M4A or OGG file.";
    }
    if($file_size > 8388608){
    $errors[]='Sorry. Your file ist quite large. Maximum file size is 8 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){

    ######################################## Directory Searcher    #############################################
    $random_number=rand();
    $file_name=$language.$random_number.$file_ext;
    foreach(glob('sounds/*') as $sound) 
    {   
        if($sound == $filename){$filename=$language.$random_number."1".$file_ext;
    }
    #############################################################################################################
        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"sounds/".$language.$file_name);
        echo "Thank you!";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
?>

<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select name="language">
    <option value="maltese">Maltese</option>
    <option value="english">English</option>
   </select>
<input type="file" name="sound" />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Well, that was fast! It works so far. It adds the language in the name, but does not delete the original name. The files look like this: englishoriginalfilename.wav or malteseoriginalfilename.wav. Also double files are just getting overwritten. Any ideas on that? And thank you so much!

Comment: take off the .$file_name before the thank you echo. you will have to add either a random number or a directory search to find what numbers are in use in the dir already, then add 1 plus the $file_ext.I'll update the answer in a mo

Comment: Now it says this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /customers/2/4/c/yuliyanilev.com/httpd.www/werkbank/thesis/uploader/index.php on line 30    I don´t see the mistake, do you?

Comment: put an ending bracket on the if line, Sorry , I didn't see it earlier

Comment: I will try this tomorrow. Thank you! You saved me from hours of headache.